# How could I specify specific gem in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to specify the 2 gems in Gemfile,

```
- activeadmin-dragonfly (0.0.2 89a47f9)
- activeadmin-wysihtml5 (1.0.0 35d1a94)
```

How could I do ?

This is my idea

```
 gem 'activeadmin-dragonfly', github: 'stefanoverna/activeadmin-dragonfly' '~> 0.0.2 89a47f9'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify version of one gem from github by adding this:

```
gem 'gem_name', github: 'author/repository_name', ref: 'ref', tag: 'tag'
```

In your case:

```
gem 'activeadmin-dragonfly', github: 'stefanoverna/activeadmin-dragonfly', ref: '89a47f9'
```

Reference: 
http://bundler.io/v1.9/git.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are okay ... I just read your question , and this is what helped me in my case ...

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'   # SSL Connection for downloading gems

# This is the start of the gem lists

gem 'gem-file-name' , 'specific gem version'
gem 'gem-file-name' , '=> gem-version'
gem 'gem-file-name' , '~> gem-version'
```

You can get only the specific gem with the first one , where the last one gets you the beta versions too ... Or if you want to have it with git repo then you can ...

```
gem 'Gem Name', :git => 'https://github.com/Username/filename.git'
```

Or to get multiple gem from Git Repo

```
git 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git' do
  gem 'railties'
  gem 'action_pack'
  gem 'active_model'
end
```

More data in http://bundler.io/v1.9/git.html

Hope this will solve your problem...